# Java `printf` `char` with `%d` causes error

Tags: java, char, integer, printf

Why does Java allow printing `int` as `char` using `%c` in `printf`, even though there is a risk of losing values, but not allow printing `char` as `int` using `%d` in `printf`, even though there is no risk of losing values?

```
System.out.printf("%c\n", 112);       // ok
System.out.printf("%d\n", 112);       // ok

System.out.printf("%c\n", 'p');       // ok
System.out.printf("%d\n", 'p');       // error --> why???

System.out.printf("%d\n", (int) 'p'); // ok
```

Comment: Your title does not match the examples you give.  The examples show no case of an error using %c.

Comment: @accessviolation: the example posted causes this: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Character` for me on the indicated line.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - the title says '%c causes error', and that is a case of %d causing an error.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the question

Answer (score 0):

There is 'no risk of losing values' by using an int argument with %c.  The argument is **not** first converted to a char datatype. See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

The specification for %c says that it will print the character if the argument is a valid codepoint, otherwise it will throw an IllegalFormatCodePointException.

Accepting an 'int' argument is necessary in order to print characters with codepoint values of 0x10000 or greater. Valid codepoints are in the range 0 to 0x10FFFF, exceeding what will fit in a single Java char.

By contrast, %d only accepts integral numeric types (not including char) because it has no reason to do otherwise.

Comment: So it's just a matter of Java design. As I have a C background, there is no problem to print char with %d.

Comment: @PedroSiqueira in this case, java-the-core-libraries design, specifically. Java-the-language has no opinion about it. This is a trend you'll find in most java libraries; If code is a tiny bit odd but easily 'clarified', java (both lang and libraries) take the route of 'spending 5 seconds to clarify this is worth it relative to guessing right 19 out of 20 times and sending you on a 5 minute bug hunt the 20th time'. Java is objectively correct in this; 5 sec * 20 is way less than 5 minutes. To clarify here, simply cast the `char`. `printf("%d\n", (int) someCharVal)` works fine.

Comment: `%d only accepts numeric types (not including char)` Also excludes float and double.

Comment: @英語は苦手 - true; I should have been more specific. Fixed now.